# own implementation of std::string::find (brute-force search)

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, implementation, brute-force

I am trying to find the occurrence of string `T` in string `P` and return the position of `T` in `P`.

This is what I have tried, but it is incorrect:

```
int bruteForce(string T, string P) {
    int n, m;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n-m; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < m && T[i+j] == P[j]) {
            if (j == m) {
                return i;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: To begin with, you are using variables `n` and `m` that were never initialized.

Comment: It's broken, `n,m` are not initialized. your code will invoke UB

Comment: Are you trying to implement `T.find(P)`?

Comment: You're making copies of the strings you are called with. You probably want "const string& T, const string& P)", but you probably ought to use better names than "T" and "P"

Answer (score 2):

In this part:

```
int n,m;
for (int i=0;i<= n-m;i++) {
```

you are using uninitialized local variable which results in **undefined behavior**. Also try to name your variables with something more meaningful than alphabet letters, I think what you actually meant was:

```
int bruteForce(std::string needle, std::string haystack) {
    int needleLen = needle.length(),
        haystackLen = haystack.length();
    for (int i = 0; i <= needleLen - haystackLen; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < haystackLen && needle[i+j] == haystack[j]) {
            if(j == haystackLen) {
                return i;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // return 0;  <-- 
}
```

also note that in your function doesn't `return` any value in case when none of `needle[i+j]` equals `haystack[j]` (for every `i`). What about the situation when `needle` is "ab" and `haystack` is "aab" ~> while comparing `needle[1]` with `haystack[1]`, your function would `return 0` (it should be placed after `for` loop)

Another reasonable change would be changing passing by value to passing by reference to avoid copies being created. And since your function doesn't change these strings, its prototype should be:

```
int bruteForce(const std::string& needle, const std::string& haystack)
```

---

And in case you didn't want to intentionally create own implementation of `std::string::find` but yet for some reason you still need it to `return 0` on failure (did you think about usage of your function when `needle` is equal to `haystack`?) it could look like this:

```
std::size_t bruteForce(const std::string& needle, const std::string& haystack) {
    std::size_t pos = haystack.find(needle);
    if (pos != std::string::npos)
        return pos;
    return 0;
}
```

...but if this is the case, you wouldn't call it `bruteForce`, would you? :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried not to alter your code too much. My changes were:

- Changed function parameters to `const reference` to avoid wasteful copies.
- The variables `n` and `m` weren't initialized.
- The inner `while` loop had problems. It didn't increment `j` and the test for success makes more sense outside the loop.
- The return value for failure can't be `0` as that may be a valid position.

Modified code (briefly tested and seems to work):

```
int bruteforce(const std::string &T, const std::string &P)
{
    int n = T.length();
    int m = P.length();
    for (int i = 0; i <= n-m; ++i) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < m && T[i+j] == P[j]) {
            ++j;
        }
        if (j == m) { // match found
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```